# Can the coefficients in ordered logit be interpreted or is it necessary to determine exp()?

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, ordered-logit, polr

When estimating an ordered logit using MASS::polr is it then possible or a good idea to interpret the coefficient from the summary output or is it necessary to determine the exp() and use the intercepts to determine the probability also?
If so, how can the coefficients then be interpreted? Can you give examples of when it's negative, positive, significant and not significant?

Comment: Are you already familiar with these concepts in logistic regression?

Comment: @AdamO not very good but I know that when odds ratio is less than 1 then there is a negative relation, if larger than 1 there is a positive relation if equal to 1 there is no relation

Comment: Or this is at least how I understooth it

Comment: Yes. And so it is with the ordered logit. The only difference with ordered logit is that the response in this case is membership in a *higher* polytomous category. That should answer your question.

Comment: @AdamO Can you give an example based on your last comment? Another question: for instance would you say that if odds ratio is 1.005 (i.e. almost =1) then there is no relationship or would you interpret it as since it's larger than 1 there is a positive relationship?

Comment: Again no need to reinvent the wheel. Small effects matter for prevalent and recurring exposures.